What is the meaning of the tensor product ($\otimes$) of groups? Is is the same as the cartesian product ($\times$)?
In the high energy physics literature and in some discussions on group theory for physics, the tensor product $\otimes$ of groups is sometimes mentioned.  For example, the gauge group of the standard model is sometimes said to be $SU(3)\otimes SU(2)\otimes U(1)$.  Is this "tensor product" really just a cartesian product/direct product, or is it something else?
Is there any difference between $SU(3)\otimes SU(2)\otimes U(1)$ and $SU(3)\times SU(2)\times U(1)$?
Note: I previously asked this question but it was closed for being more about "history of science" (?) than physics.  I hope the rephrased version here is more on-topic.

There is no tensor product of groups AFAIK, physicists just like to use the fancy symbol.

@Javier one could take the groups to act on the hilbert space $\Bbb C^3\otimes\Bbb C^2\otimes\Bbb C$, i. e. take the tensor product of representations of the groups. In my (arguably limited) experience, there is rarely any difference between using a group or its representation as an action on a vector space.

@paulina There is a difference as there are a multitude of representations per group. Some properties are inherent to groups while others are only true for certain (types) of representations.  But i agree that the notation probably stems from there and that people are often sloppy distinguishing reps and groups.

i meant that in practical calculations, one rarely makes a difference between the group and a specific representation of it.

Near duplicate. Also see this.
